# Change list item background in custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I have custom adapter and I want pick out new messages. My adapter looks like. New messages have new_message icon.

```
public class InputMessagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private List<Message> messageList;
private List<SellerStatement> sellerStatementList;
private List<Integer> messagesIds;
private String arrayName = "messagesIds";
private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public InputMessagesAdapter(Context context, List<Message> messageList, List<SellerStatement> sellerStatementList) {
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.sellerStatementList = sellerStatementList;
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);
        Integer[] tempArray = new Integer[size];

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            tempArray[i] = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_" + i, -1);

        messagesIds = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(tempArray));
    }

    @Override
        public int getCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return messageList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        Message message = messageList.get(position);

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages_new_row, null);
        }

        TextView subject = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSubject);
        TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        TextView sender = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSender);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imMessage);


        SellerStatement sellerStatement = sellerStatementList.get(position);

        subject.setText(message.getSubject());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        date.setText(String.valueOf(sdf.format(message.getTimestamp())));
        sender.setText(sellerStatement.getSender().getGoogleAccount());

        Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.old_message);

        if(!messagesIds.contains(message.getMessageId()))
            image = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_message);


        icon.setImageDrawable(image);

        return view;
    }
}
```

I try it, but all items change color.

```
if(!messagesIds.contains(message.getMessageId())) {
    image = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_message);
    view.setBackgroundColor(COLOR);
}
```

And this work incorrect too (I change background color for layout)

```
View view = convertView;
if (view == null) {
    if(!messagesIds.contains(message.getMessageId())) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages_new_row, null);
    } else {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages_row, null);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple:

```
 View view = convertView; //find this line in your code
 view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN); //add this line below
```

Comment: This is work incorrect. After scroll list, all items is same.

Comment: @ViT-Vetal- yes it is! If you want different colors, you should create ArrayList<Integer> myColors, and put there colors for each list item, and then view.setBackgroundColor(myColors.get(position));

Comment: @ViT-Vetal- and "each color for each item" is a different question. My answer is correct for current question "Change list item background in custom adapter".

Answer (score 1):

After update the adapter use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to force the List to redraw

Comment: Thank you for this. I had inconsistent behaviour for not calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the time you create your adapter and it creates your views, *all* the message id's are in the list, therefore, `!messagesIds.contains(message.getMessageId())` will allways be false.

At the moment you add a new message to the message list, you have to call the `notifyDatasetChanged()`method on your `Adapter`. This will create all views again and add your new message with the new icon and background color

Comment: You are mistaken. 
!messagesIds.contains(message.getMessageId()) - it works.